# How can i add eventListener on TabListener?

Tags: android

I am working in android. I am designing a `TabHost`, in which I want to add `onclickListener()`.
So by selecting a particular tab i can display the list of songs.

This is my code for create a `TabHost`:

```
int number_of_tab=number_of_records/4;
        for(int i=0;i<number_of_tab;i++)
        {
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this,Latest_MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("EX_START_POINT", i);
        Log.v(TAG,"---album activity is called---" + "---the value of i---" + i);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(i+"").setIndicator("Albums",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        Log.v(TAG,"---tabHost.getCurrentTabTag()--->>"+tabHost.getCurrentTabTag());

        }
```

I want to know eventListener, so please suggest the code for that.

This is another function which is exist in second class:

```
 void makeListOfSongs()
    {

                 Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
         display_tag=extras.getInt("EX_START_POINT");
         for (int i = display_tag*10; i < display_tag+5; i++) {
            musicid[i] = new TextView(this);
            musicid[i].setText("Music Id = "+sitesList.getMusicId().get(i));

            title[i] = new TextView(this);
            title[i].setText("Title = "+sitesList.getTitle().get(i));
            title_of_song[i]=sitesList.getTitle().get(i);

            layout.addView(musicid[i]);
            layout.addView(title[i]);

        }
```

So if i select the first tab then list of song from 10 to 15 should display in list, if i select tab 2 then song from 20 to 25 should show in the list. So please suggest me what should i do to make such type of event Listener on the tabhost.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a onTabChangedListener to the tab host like

> mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new
>   OnTabChangeListener() {
>
> ```
>         @Override
>         public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
>
>
>         }
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for my above question :- i have solved this problem by taking help of google:-

1. implement OnTabChangeListener interface on your activity.
2. override the method onTabChanged()

   public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
    {
       //do  here whatever you want
    }

Comment: isnt this exactly the answer i've given.

Comment: yes sir thats why i accepted your answer and up voted your answer... i write here my answer here also so any person who visit this link in future having same problem can solve his or her problem easily...

Comment: i got the upvote but no answer is set as selected. You might need to check that.